# Aurelia nested repeat.for context of parent repeat.for

Tags: aurelia

When nesting `repeat.for` in Aurelia, an internal `repeat.for` does not have access to the variable used in it's parent `repeat.for`.

### Example

```
<div repeat.for="x of 8">
  <div repeat.for="y of 8">
    ${x} - ${y}
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above example, `${x}` does not emit anything. How do you get the `x` value when inside the internal `repeat.for`?

Answer (score 6):

Found my answer. You need to do the following:

```
<div repeat.for="x of 8">
  <div repeat.for="y of 8">
    ${$parent.x} - ${y}
  </div>
</div>
```